# How to query the associations of an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do the following to get a list of all the reviews for a business:

```
@business.professionals.reviews
```

I am not concerned about which professional the reviews belong to, but I want the reviews returned in the same format as professionals would be returned in `@business.professionals`

**In my example, businesses have many professionals, and professionals have many reviews.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your business model

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :professionals
  has_many :visible_reviews, :through => :professionals, :class_name => "Review", :source => :reviews :conditions => ['prefessionals.reviews_visible = ?',true]
  has_many :reviews, :through => :professionals
end
```

And now you can get all the reviews of all professionals using

```
@business.visible_reviews
```

Comment: Hi it is a bit more complicated than this. I have this association defined already, but I actually have some professionals who set their reviews to private, so I need to do something like @business.professionals.where("reviews_visible" => true).reviews

Comment: Oh that's great. Do you know by chance how to make this a scope so I can still access all the reviews if need be? I'd rather not overwrite my association as sometimes I need to get the full list of reviews

Comment: You can define two associations one for reviews and other for visible_reviews

Comment: Thanks. I wish rails was smart enough to do all this with the DSL like @business.professionals.where("reviews_visible" => true).reviews